# What is the difference between gsub and sub methods for Ruby Strings

Tags: ruby, string

I have been perusing the documentation for `String` today, and I saw the `:sub` method, which I'd never noticed before.  I've been using `:gsub` and it appears that they are essentially the same.  Can anyone explain the difference to me?  Thanks!

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html

Answer (score 234, accepted):

The `g` stands for global, as in replace globally (all):

In irb:

```
>> "hello".sub('l', '*')
=> "he*lo"
>> "hello".gsub('l', '*')
=> "he**o"
```

Comment: Yeah. I understand now.  In my defense, I don't think this was very obvious... Until now, that is.

Comment: I agree with you that it is not obvious!  Java calls these `replace` and `replaceAll`.  But Ruby has its roots in Perl which uses the `g` modifier.  It's just one of those things.

Comment: Fortunately, it is now obvious.  I'll know in the future.

Comment: By the way, `sub` is much faster than `gsub`, there is an benchmark here https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby/blob/master/code/string/gsub-vs-sub.rb

Comment: I'm seeing some differing behavior to this:

```A, sentence, separated, by, commas".gsub!(/(.*),(.*)/,"\\2 \\1")
=> " commas A, sentence, separated, by"```

Any thoughts why `gsub!` only seems to be finding/replacing only the first instance when using regex groups?

Comment: Try the regex `/(.*?),(.*?)/` and note the difference :)

Comment: This confused me first, so I would like to note that, if you use this on a multi-line file, the difference seems to be counted _per line_. Meaning: `sub` and `gsub` both will replace the string in all lines, but only `gsub` will replace multiple occurrences in the same line.

Answer (score 41):

The difference is that `sub` only replaces the first occurrence of the pattern specified, whereas `gsub` does it for all occurrences (that is, it replaces globally).

Comment: If you'd answered one minute earlier, maybe 1020 more rep would have been yours. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
value = "abc abc"
puts value                                # abc abc
# Sub replaces just the first instance.
value = value.sub("abc", "---")
puts value                                # --- abc
# Gsub replaces all instances.
value = value.gsub("abc", "---")
puts value                                # --- ---
```

Answer (score -1):

`sub` and `gsub` perform replacement of the first and all matches respectively.

```
sub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
    fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
     fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)


sub("4", "8", "An Introduction to R Software Course will be of 4 weeks duration" )  
##"An Introduction to R Software Course will be of 8 weeks duration"

gsub("4", "8", "An Introduction to R Software Course will be of 4 weeks duration" )
##"An Introduction to R Software Course will be of 8 weeks duration"
```