# Remove spaces and numbers in text analysis

Tags: r, twitter

I've doing an extract of twitter with R, but when analysing the output I get a lot of spaces counted and also numbers. How can I remove these

I'm using the following code:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter('weather', n=10,lang='en')
t <- twListToDF(tweets)
tw.text <- t[,"text"]
tw.text <- tolower(tw.text)
tw.text <- removeWords(tw.text,c(stopwords('en'),'rt'))
tw.text <- removePunctuation(tw.text,TRUE)
tw.text <- unlist(strsplit(tw.text,' '))
word <- sort(table(tw.text),TRUE)
wordc <- head(word,n=10)
```

When I run wordc I get the following:

```
> wordc
tw.text
                       RT      weather       County          EST       Severe Thunderstorm      Warning           25        430PM 
          31            4            4            3            3            3            3            3            2            2
```

As you see I get 31 entries blanks, 2 entries with the number 25 and 2 entries with 430PM. How can I remove these types of entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `tw.text <- unlist(strsplit(tw.text,' '))`, you have a vector of text elements. You can use a `sub` and a `which` function to get the values which aren't blank. Here's an example:

```
foo <- c("hi"," ","     ","test")
bar <- foo[which(sub(" +","",foo)!="")]
length(bar)
[1] 2
print(bar)
[1] "hi"   "test"
```

Of course, if you want all the spaces removed from each entry, you can move the `sub` function around to store the stripped values (ie. `sub(" +","",foo)` gives you a vector with no whitespace)

Comment: Thank Jeff. That gets read of the spaces!! Any idea how to get read of the numbers?

Comment: It may be worth reading a little bit about [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), or RegEx. You can use the substitution family of functions (`grep`, `sub`, `gsub`, etc.) to find elements which match a regular expression you have in mind. In this case `sub("[0-9]+","",bar)` will remove numbers. [This site](https://regex101.com/) is a good resource to test your logic and be able to visualize what you are doing with regular expressions (and has a handy guide on the right).

Comment: By the way, I have (probably) learned some bad coding habits over the years, so see [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6766915/4709191) for an explanation as when to use `sub` vs `gsub`. With `gsub`, my previous comment becomes more somewhat more readable, `gsub("[0-9]","",bar)` ie. replace globally any number in `bar` with blank space `""`.